# Mail function not working on online server

Tags: php, email, header, message

i write a perfect code but i dont understand why my mail not send

```
$to = "info@domain.com";
    $subject = "Account request from $first_name $last_name";
    $emailBody = "
            hi,
            <br /><br />
            <strong>First Name</strong> : $first_name.<br />
            <strong>Last Name</strong> : $last_name.<br />
            <strong>Phone</strong> : $phone.<br />
            <strong>Email</strong> : $email.<br />
            <strong>Message</strong> : $message.
    ";

    //  Email headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: domain' . "\r\n";

    //  Email Function
    $mail = mail($to,$subject,$emailBody,$headers);
```

if i check in condtion

```
if($mail)
{
echo 'success';
}
else
{
echo 'fail';
}
```

on Localhost it shows me success but on online server it shows me fail - idont understand why????

Comment: Any php errors? Is there anything else on this page?

Comment: no there is no error in php

Comment: Have you got a configured mail server or sendmail for it to use on that server?

Comment: Check the help on your hosting companies site. There are often rules that you have to comply with specific to emailing. Also it could well be that their email server does not like your `from address`. It probably has to be a valid email address and has to exists.

Comment: `$headers .= 'From: domain' . "\r\n";` This looks wrong to me, I think you must put an email address in the from header, or a name followed by the email address. `From: Dale <dale@whatever.museum>\r\n`

Comment: do you communicate with hosting provider...?They may be handle your queries..

Comment: thanx to all of u error on "From"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i make a mistake on From

first i write this

```
$headers .= 'From: domain' . "\r\n";
```

Now this is correct

```
$headers .= 'From: Domain <info@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Thanx to all of u specially "RiggsFolly" & "Dale"